# how to find the size of set in python?

Tags: set, size

import `sys`

# sample Sets

Set1 `=` `{"A", 1, "B", 2, "C", 3}`

Set2 `=` `{"Geek1", "Raju", "Geek2", "Nikhil", "Geek3", "Deepanshu"}`

Set3 `=` `{(1, "Lion"), ( 2, "Tiger"), (3, "Fox")}`

# print the sizes of sample Sets

print`("Size of Set1: "` `+` `str(sys.getsizeof(Set1)) +` `"bytes")`

print`("Size of Set2: "` `+` `str(sys.getsizeof(Set2)) +` `"bytes")`

print`("Size of Set3: "` `+` `str(sys.getsizeof(Set3)) +` `"bytes")`

A set is an unordered collection data type that is iterable, mutable, and has no duplicate elements. Python's set class represents the mathematical notatation of a set. The size of a set means the amount of memory(in bytes) occupied by a set object.

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question?

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title: **Use `len()` to get the size of a set.**

Semantically that is a bit weird, as a set is an unordered collection, and the length analogy kind of breaks down (we are actually measuring *cardinality*), but in the spirit of Python using `len` to get the size of all kinds of collections is easy to remember and it is quite obvious what the statement means.